# Функция проверки вводимых значений на соответствие типу

Tags: java

В задаче необходимо сделать функцию проверки вводимых значений на соответствие тому или иному типу. Так вот вопрос какими средствами это можно реализовать в java? И приведите, пожалуйста, пример если не сложно.

Comment: имеется ввиду соответствует ли типу double или int ?

Comment: вводится строка или неизвестный тип?

Comment: А как можно ввести "неизвестный тип"?

я думаю, вводит он строку и хочет убедиться, что это именно целое или вещественное.

Comment: как Object

Comment: Да, вводится массив и необходимо определить целочисленный или вещественный.

Comment: @inham130, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @deterok Сам я выполнил первую часть задачи: 1. Реализовать приложение, для введенной с консоли последо-вательности целых чисел вычисляющее среднее значение. В качестве объек-та, применяемого для хранения последовательности целых чисел, ис-пользовать массив. 
Однако как реализовать вторую часть, озвученную в вопросе я не знал и потому попросил подсказку. Я не просил решать за меня задачу. Я спросил о средствах и попросил привести пример. К тому я делаю эту задачу для изучения языка, а не для получения зачета или еще чего либо.

Comment: @inham130, вот если бы Вы сразу написали в вопросе условие задачи, то поучили бы конкретный ответ, а не кучу кода, решающего совсем другую задачу.

--

Вам же нужно просто привести тип переменной с накопленной
суммой к `double` и разделить ее на количество элементов.

     long sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         sum += a[i]; // накапливаем сумму массива из n элементов
     System.out.println ("Average: " + (double)sum / n);

--

IMHO, простейший способ проверить переменную 

     static String isint (double d) {
       return (long)d == d ? "Really int" : "Not int";
     }

Comment: @avp то что я написал в комментарии выше я уже сделал. Мне необходимо было научиться определять тип вводимых значений.что я тоже уже сделал. Но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерная канва решения:

```
String s; //введенное юзером значение

try {
   if((s.toLowerCase().contains('e') || s.toLowerCase().contains('.'))
      double d=Double.parseDouble(s); //вещественный тип
   else 
      long l=Long.parseLong(s); //целый тип
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //строчный тип
}
```

P.S. Не компилировал и не проверял, я не компилятор :)

Answer (score 5):

Я так понял Вам нужно определить тип переменной, я не большой специалист в Java но вижу два способа:
 1. Java  Строго типизированный язык, значит можно сохранить в массиве все типы и делать проверку типа объекта оператором instanceof:

1. Сделать свой тестер, что-то вроде

   ```
   class Typetester {
       void printType(byte x) {
           System.out.println(x + " is an byte");
       }
       void printType(int x) {
           System.out.println(x + " is an int");
       }
       void printType(float x) {
           System.out.println(x + " is an float");
       }
       void printType(double x) {
           System.out.println(x + " is an double");
       }
       void printType(char x) {
           System.out.println(x + " is an char");
       }
   }
   ```

Потом создать объект и пошло-поехало...

```
Typetester testMe = new Typetester();
testMe.printType( testedVariable );
```

Comment: А если мне не известно, какой тип пользователь собирается вводить, но как я понимаю, для проверки вначале нужно куда - то сохранить вводимые данные. Так вот как с этим быть?

Comment: Читаете данные в строку и посимвольно анализируете ее (или используете для анализа *регулярные выражения*)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (var instanceof Type1) {
    …
} else if (var instanceof Type2) {
    …
}
…
```

Answer (score 3):

Итак, у вас есть строковое значение, и вам необходимо проверить, является ли оно представлением заданного типа.

Для встроенных типов это не так сложно:

`int`:

```
Integer tryParseInt(String s) {
    try {
        return new Integer(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null; // не-а, не int
    }
}
```

`double`:

```
Double tryParseDouble(String s) {
    try {
        return new Double(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null; // не-а, не double
    }
}
```

`String`:

```
String tryParseString(String s) {
    return s; // всегда подходит
}
```

и т. д.

Кастомные типы должны уметь распознавать себя сами. Если они не умеют, «распознавалку» придётся писать вручную для каждого из типов.

Пользоваться так:

```
String s = getUserInput();
// попробовать int
Integer v = tryParseInt(s);
if (v != null) {
    // распознано, результат в v
}
else {
    // не распознано
}
```

Comment: Только лучше не `new Integer()` и не `new Double()`, а `Integer.valueOf()` и `Double.valueOf()` соответственно, поскольку в этом случае будет задействован кэш значений.

Comment: @falstaf: Не уверен, [документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) говорит, что `valueOf(String)` делает то же, что и `new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))`. Обещание насчёт кеширования есть только для [`valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29).

Comment: эм...в Integer кэшируются только числа в диапазоне от -128 до 127, в не зависимости от получения ;-) в Double кэширования нет.
В Integer это сделано для небольшой оптимизации, например для циклов.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void valueOf (String str) {
    Format parser = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parseObject(str);
        if (obj instanceof Double) {
            System.out.println("double");
        } else if (obj instanceof Long) {
            System.out.println("long");
        } else {
            new ParseException("WTF?", 0);
        }
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal value: " + str);
    }
}
```

Может так?;-)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал проверкой регулярным значением.

```
String inputData = "12345";
if(inputData.match("\\d")){
  System.out.println("It is number");
  int number = Integer.valueOf(inputData);
}

if(inputData.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")){
  System.out.println("It is double");
  double number = Double.valueOf(inputData);
}
```

P.S. Загонять в Integer или Double и ждать Exception, не есть очень хорошо! Программе приходиться останавливаться и собирать стректрейс, а это операция не быстрая. Тем более это не исключительная ситуация для вашей программы.
Не раз встречал парсинг строки в цифру с Exception у коллег, и приходилось им объяснять. Но судя по ответам это делают почти все, что очень грустно.

Answer (score 2):

Решал подобную задачу на JavaRush, возможно, не самым элегантным, но работающим способом. По вводимому значению вызывается перегруженный под разные типы данных метод print. Ввод прекращается после ввода "exit"

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int val;
    boolean out = false;
    while(!out) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            val = sc.nextInt();
            if ((-32768 < val)&&(val < 32767)) print((short) val);
            else{
                print(val);
            }
        }
        else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) print(sc.nextDouble());
        else if (sc.hasNextLine()&&(!sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("exit"))) {
            print(sc.nextLine());
        }
        else {
            out = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

А какой смысл? Когда вам придётся вызывать метод например из класса Scanner вы будете присваивать введённый ответ какой-то переменной, а по правилам Java при инициализации переменной нужно сразу указывать тип.